# Same memory address for different processes

Tags: c, memory-management, shared-memory

I just can't figure out why this code works the way it does (rather than I'd expect):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/wait.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>

 int main()
 {
     int buffer;
     int* address;

     address=&buffer;


     if(fork()==0)
     {
         *address=27;
         printf("Address %ld stores %d\n",(long)address,*address);
         exit(0);
     }
     wait(NULL);

     printf("Address %ld stores %d\n",(long)(&buffer),buffer);    
     return 0;
 }
```

Why does the system store different variables even if they're pointed to the same memory address?

NOTE: I never really expected this code to work, since otherwise the whole bunch of pipes and stuff wouldn't make any sense; I'd just like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: What is your output and what do you expect? I expect a garbage value for `buffer` and that is what I get: https://ideone.com/ESqx1I

Comment: You have to familiarize yourself with the difference between physical and virtual memory addresses

Comment: @mch That's what I get as well, it just feels weird to read something like: Memory adrress X stores 27, and memory address X stores 0 (I mean, provided X=X...)

Comment: @Ctx it looks like I'm thinking of virtual memory as though it was physical. Is there a way to force a proces to write in a specific physical address anyway?

Comment: @Guillermo.D.S. There is no portable way to write to a specific physical address but I do not see a good reason for this anyway. There are other mechanisms for sharing memory between processes for example (threads, posix shared memory, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't really a C question, it's about the behavior of (modern) operating systems.

In short: A userspace program on a modern OS runs in some private **virtual** address space. When accessing memory, the virtual address is translated to a physical address. The mapping between actual memory and virtual address space is set up by the operating system -- the memory is split into pages and a page can be "mapped" into the address space of a process.

`fork()` typically just maps the same memory to the second process it creates, but as soon as this memory is written to, the page is copied and the copy is mapped ("copy on write"). A user space program will never see memory that is private to a different user space program.

I'm sure you can easily find more details searching for the key words given in this answer.

Comment: Thx @Felix Palmen. So it's all up to the OS? isn't there any trick to force a process to write within a specific physical address?

Comment: @Guillermo.D.S. also look up MMU (memory management unit) .. the translation of addresses is done *in hardware*, so, no, there isn't a way around for a process that doesn't have kernel privileges, at least not without a hardware flaw or some exploitable hole in the OS itself. Only the kernel can set up the page tables used by the MMU.

Comment: Indeed there _are_ sometimes OS-specific ways (under intel linux, for example, you can map /dev/mem). But this is higly platform and architecture specific.

Comment: @Ctx yes, but if there are such mechanisms, they are typically reserved to some "privileged" processes. And it's still the kernel actually accessing the physical memory.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes, of course, you have to be root (or change the permissions of /dev/mem). But no, it is not the kernel then, but the pages are mapped directly into the processes virtual memory

Comment: @Ctx `/dev/mem` provides a character device as an "image" of the physical memory. Of course, you can request a mapping on it, but that's still something the kernel has to do...

Comment: @FelixPalmen It is _always_ the kernel mapping the memory, but it is not the kernel proxying access to the pages. There is not much technical difference between mmapping /dev/mem or doing a brk() to increment the heap.

Comment: @Ctx and still you can also just read from /dev/mem, without mapping it. And when you get it mapped, the access again goes through the MMU ... well, I guess the point got through ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes, you are correct, all read/write operations are still translated by the mmu. In that sense, it is not _direct_ physical memory access.

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)): The fork operation creates a separate address space for the child. The child process has an exact copy of all the memory segments of the parent process.

So basically you create a new process with a different COPY of your original process memory.
You change something on the duplicate process's memory, which is identical but a copy and expect to see it in the original.
Normally, processes don't share memory directly.